# Define Apoggiato

Tags: baroque-period, bowing

I came across this term, **Apoggiato**. In baroque music, is understand that this means the notes of a piece marked thus should be quite smoothly connected, almost portato.

The Online Musical Dictionary says, "Leaned upon, drawn out", but I don't know what that means.

Comments, please?

Answer (score 2):

That certainly is a rarely used term!  I found one definition via Google Books, "Encyclopaedic Dictionary of Music edited by Hugo Riemann," as

> same as "appogiando," meaning "leaning against. These terms are
>   applied to notes which are connected to others -- syncopations and
>   suspensions - and are synonymous with 'col portamento di voce'

[musicwithease](http://www.musicwithease.com/music-dictionary-a.html) has the same wording.

Answer (score 0):

When I see this marked, I would play the note to its fullest capacity (not cut it short). 'Leaned upon' is not particularly good in describing the nature of the ornament however is very accurate in the way you play it... try 'leaning on' a note when you play and you will understand.